# Query regarding the signup process and profile picture on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, profile-page

I am a new user who has just registered today to your site (though I have been using Stack Overflow for getting answers to my queries).

The Signup form takes the most basic information about the user, i.e. email, username/password.
But, what I was shocked to see after logging in was that my profile already has my picture imported from Wordpress?

I hadn't specified my Wordpress OpenId. Then how come my profile pic got imported? Though not an issue, just curious because somehow, to me, it looked like a privacy leak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Overflow uses [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) to get avatars.

WordPress uses this as well. In fact there's a big

> WordPress.com user? Log in!

section on the Gravatar home page.

Comment: True. @GirijaAcharya - this is all linked through the email address: it's being hashed into unique identifier which is then used by Gravatar. So when using same email for WordPress and for this place, you'll indeed have the same Gravatar. (For example your hash is `daf9cd113d175b4cfb9cdd59580ddd77` used [here](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/daf9cd113d175b4cfb9cdd59580ddd77))